# intersectRaySphere x86 fpu asm routine - how to optymize

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86, fpu

Hullo, i ve got some c procedure :

```
    inline float intersectRaySphere(float3* rayO, float3* rayV, float3* sO, float sR)
    {
    static float3 Q;

    Q = sub(sO,rayO);

    float cc = dot(&Q,&Q);
    float v = dot(&Q,rayV);
    float d = sR*sR - (cc - v*v);

    // If there was no intersection, return -1
    if (d < 0.0) return (-1.0f);
    // Return the distance to the [first] intersecting point
    return (v - sqrt(d));
    }
```

I was trying to rewrite it in x86 fpu asm and create such one

```
    _asm_intersectRaySphere:; Function begin
    push    ebp                                     ; 0000 _ 55
    mov     ebp, esp                                ; 0001 _ 89. E5
    add     esp, -20                                ; 0003 _ 83. C4, EC
    mov     eax, dword [ebp+8H]                     ; 0006 _ 8B. 45, 08
    mov     ecx, dword [ebp+0CH]                    ; 0009 _ 8B. 4D, 0C
    mov     edx, dword [ebp+10H]                    ; 000C _ 8B. 55, 10
    fld     dword [edx]                             ; 000F _ D9. 02
    fsub    dword [eax]                             ; 0011 _ D8. 20
    fld     dword [edx+4H]                          ; 0013 _ D9. 42, 04
    fsub    dword [eax+4H]                          ; 0016 _ D8. 60, 04
    fld     dword [edx+8H]                          ; 0019 _ D9. 42, 08
    fsub    dword [eax+8H]                          ; 001C _ D8. 60, 08
    fld     st2                                     ; 001F _ D9. C2
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0021 _ DC. C8
    fld     st2                                     ; 0023 _ D9. C2
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0025 _ DC. C8
    fld     st2                                     ; 0027 _ D9. C2
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0029 _ DC. C8
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 002B _ DE. C1
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 002D _ DE. C1
    fld     dword [ecx]                             ; 002F _ D9. 01
    fmul    st(0), st4                              ; 0031 _ D8. CC
    fld     dword [ecx+4H]                          ; 0033 _ D9. 41, 04
    fmul    st(0), st4                              ; 0036 _ D8. CC
    fld     dword [ecx+8H]                          ; 0038 _ D9. 41, 08
    fmul    st(0), st4                              ; 003B _ D8. CC
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 003D _ DE. C1
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 003F _ DE. C1
    fst     dword [ebp-4H]                          ; 0041 _ D9. 55, FC
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0044 _ DC. C8
    fld     dword [ebp+14H]                         ; 0046 _ D9. 45, 14
    fmul    st0, st(0)                              ; 0049 _ DC. C8
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              ; 004B _ DE. C1
    fsubrp  st1, st(0)                              ; 004D _ DE. E1
    fxch    st3                                     ; 004F _ D9. CB
    fstp    st0                                     ; 0051 _ DD. D8
    fstp    st0                                     ; 0053 _ DD. D8
    fstp    st0                                     ; 0055 _ DD. D8
    ftst                                            ; 0057 _ D9. E4
    fwait                                           ; 0059 _ 9B
    fnstsw  ax                                      ; 005A _ DF. E0
    fwait                                           ; 005C _ 9B
    sahf                                            ; 005D _ 9E
    jc      ?_001                                   ; 005E _ 72, 07
    fsqrt                                           ; 0060 _ D9. FA
    fsubr   dword [ebp-4H]                          ; 0062 _ D8. 6D, FC
    jmp     ?_002                                   ; 0065 _ EB, 06

     ?_001:  
    fstp    st0                                     ; 0067 _ DD. D8
    fld1                                            ; 0069 _ D9. E8
    fchs                                            ; 006B _ D9. E0
     ?_002:  
    mov     esp, ebp                                ; 006D _ 89. EC
    pop     ebp                                     ; 006F _ 5D
    ret                                             ; 0070 _ C3
    ; _asm_intersectRaySphere End of function
```

tested, and it is working ok, c routine takes about 150 cycles (on my 6 or
7 years old old pentium 4), my asm routine takes about 66 cycles (*) - so it is 
good improvement, but maybe it can be also yet improved a little ?

tnx

(*) i was testing with not much care, on random input data so 
possibly it was a 'non intersection' cause - with no sqrt involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace this:

```
fstp st0
fstp st0
fstp st0
ftst
fwait
fnstsw  ax
fwait
sahf
jc ?__001
```

By this:

```
fcompp
fstp st0
fldz
fcomip st0, st1
ja ?__001
```

`fnstsw` isn't fast, and `sahf` isn't great either, especially not on P4's. If you can't use `fcomi` (ie if it has to work on P1 or PMMX), you can still skip the `sahf` by testing a bit in `ax` directly.

Comment: seem to be slight improvement about 1 - 2 cycle, sometimes it is hard to say because I had in some way dirrerent outcome in different runs, sometimes 68 for example sometimes 65 - same was with 'classic' normalize on fpu - sometimes 90 sometimes 80 :/ (for example my initial version with fld xyz fld xyz store was 90, improved with one fld xyz and stack storing was also 90 but when i measured initial then it become 80 - somewhat strange)

Comment: @grungefightr ok, this wasn't going to help much of course, but I would have expected a bit more than that (maybe 4 to 6 cycles).

Comment: allright, it is okay - my measurings are not so high precise, i want just to get the general idea with fpu - still i belive that there may exist more rules tu optymise such fpu code up - but do not matter - some day l8ter will buy new processor with avx and try to rewrite most important pieces under avx, now i want to train to get ready l8er ;-)

Comment: 65 is good, (very good) besides, when 'normalise' which is only common add, and do not do real geometric calculation work, takes 80 (do not tried with tricky invsqry (29) yet - maybe will be faster - do not tried sse version also yet) [though 65 is probably because i do test it with such data where intersection do not occur and no sqrt is called]

Comment: You shouldn't really test this on random data by the way. I'm fairly sure that if you tested this on the same real data all the time, the numbers would make much more sense. And they would probably be higher too - 65 is really too low for that square root to have happened a significant percentage of the time.

Comment: ye, i think so, As to random data I meen i give to it some randomizely written data with hand ) specificaly ` static  float3 avv = {100,100,100};   static  float3 bvv = {1,2,1};   static  float3 cvv = {10,20,13}; ` It is the same all the time but probably no intersection do occur ;-)

Comment: It may be more useful to take an actual scene as benchmark - then you're optimizing for a real case that will really happen. Otherwise it's easy to accidentally make tracing an empty scene really quickly (at the expense of filled scenes), but that's not very useful.

Comment: ye, i will be testing real pixels now, but whole pixel route procedure is long, about 300 lines - but will measure it i am curious how many cycles per pixel this is

Comment: as to opty,misation rules - I heard about some tehnique of 'less dependency chains' (to allow moachine to paralelise some lines) - should it work also with fpu here ??

Comment: @grungefightr the dependency chains rule applies to the fpu as well, but there isn't much you can do in this case is there?

Comment: do not know, had no experience - but maybe interleaving fadds with fmulls ? It was reading just now that fadds and fmulls can be paralelised (looking through great agner fog manuals :/)